# Access the 2D index of an element while running an apply function over it in pandas/numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to iterate over an array in numpy and **applying a function over every element using some calculation on the index**. So I have code that looks something like this:

```
# f takes in a matrix element and returns some calculation based on the
# element's 2D index i,j
def f(elt, i,j):

      return elt*i + elt*j

# create a 2x3 matrix, A
A = np.array([[1,2,3]
              [4,5,6]])


# Transform A by applying the function `f` over every element.
A_1 = applyFunction(f, A)


print(A_1)
# A_1 should now be a matrix that is transformed:
# [[0  2  6]
   [4 10 18]
```

#### It is very easy to do this using a for-loop, but my matrix is so big that it is not efficient to do so in this case. I am trying to use numpy's builtin methods like `apply` or `apply_along_axis`

I have also thought about converting the matrix to a pandas DataFrame and then maybe using the column and row names as the indices.. but I don't know how to have access to that in an `apply_along_axis` function call.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `np.indices(A.shape)` should help you get started

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand how that helps. This just gives me a matrix with row indices

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are even asking.  Your dummy function makes no sense, since it just returns what it is being passed.  You'll have better luck providing an [mcve]

Comment: Your `A1` looks like list of lists of tuples.

Comment: `A_1` is meant to be the transformed matrix. I'll edit my quesiton to clarify

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis` expects a function that accepts a 1d array (not scalars), and iterates over the other axes, calling that function once for combination.  It's still a loop (look at its code yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def f(elt, i,j):
      return (i,j)

A = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]

In [306]: [[f(None,i,j) for j in range(len(A[0]))] for i in range(len(A))] 
Out[306]: [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)], [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]]
```

An array solution, with probably about the same speed:

```
In [309]: np.frompyfunc(f,3,1)(None, [[0],[1]],[0,1,2])
Out[309]: 
array([[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
       [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]], dtype=object)
In [310]: _.shape
Out[310]: (2, 3)
```

Fastest numpy approach, but doesn't use your `f` function:

```
In [312]: I,J = np.meshgrid(range(2),range(3),indexing='ij')
In [313]: I
Out[313]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
In [314]: J
Out[314]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
In [315]: np.stack((I,J), axis=2)
Out[315]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]]])
In [316]: _.shape
Out[316]: (2, 3, 2)
```

Comment: This uses for loops. This takes too long

Comment: But your function only takes one `i` and `j` at a time.  It has to be called once for each element of `A`.  Each of those function calls takes time.

Comment: It's easy to make a 3d array of these indices - but it won't use your `f` function.